# How do I make environment variables available in Grove?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf, marklogic-10

I am developing a UI application using [MarkLogic Grove](https://developer.marklogic.com/code/grove/)(React).
And I want to use different settings in the application depending on the environment.
For that, I want to use environment variables.

I wrote as follows.

- ui/src/.env

```
    TEST="test01"
```

- ui/src/App.js

```
    const valueFromEnv = process.env.TEST;   
    const App = appProps => (
      <AppContainer
        {...appProps}
        render={props => (
          <div> x{valueFromEnv}y
      …
```

But, "test01" was not displayed on the browser(Only "xy" was displayed.).
How do I make environment variables available in Grove?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix any env variable you'd like to expose with `REACT_APP_`, otherwise they won't be exposed inside your frontend code. It is explained in more detail here:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

HTH!

Comment: I renamed the environment variable to REACT_APP_TEST, but it didn't resolve the issue.
Does MarkLogic Grove require special settings to use environment variables?

Comment: Keep in mind that you then have to access it with process.env.REACT_APP_TEST. It is regular React app behavior, nothing Grove specific.

Comment: Oh.. it may help to put that .env one folder higher, not in ui/src/, but in ui/..